Making LaTeX automatically calculating sums
I would like to enhance out LaTeX document with some automated calculations like following:
Total: 6
  Subtotal 1: 2
    Value 1: 1
    Value 2: 1
  Subtotal 1: 4
    Value 1: 2
    Value 2: 2

The values are entered inside the text, same as total and subtotal values. Which means, all the data is not stored in form of a table or similar.
I assume, on the firs run, I would require some output file to store the values from the text. On the secont run, I would then perform the calculations and use them for total and subtotals.
However, this is the part of LaTeX I am not familiar with. Also, googling did not bring me to any good result. Any suggestion on possible solution or where I could get more information about this topic?

Have a look at the totcount package

please provide a minimal example for people to play with. this should show how you are entering the values and the syntax you'd like to use to produce the totals/subtotals.

Not at all what you asked, but if you've heard of R language and  knitr, you can add without any external file a chunk of R language to define variables (e.g. a=1; b=2) and the sum of them (c=a+b)  and then place the a, b or c variables where you want in the LaTeX text (e.g. \Sexpr{c}}) and more.  This example shows that it is not only useful for simple arithmetic calculations.

Is it not a convention, that a calculation has to be top/down?

No offense to all who answered, but is it not weird, that a simple addition produces such codemonsters?

Please provide a minimal example next time.
Hooking into the new properties infrastructure provided by the LaTeX kernel is one option. The syntax below may look weirdly alien. I completely get this response and it could be rewritten using the LaTeX 2e interface. However, doing it this way is much clearer once you are used to it.
Using the properties framework has several advantages:

It gets you a setup for writing values with labels to the .aux file which is as straightforward as the familiar \label/\ref system and, in fact, works in much the same way.
It provides a ready-made interface for setting up defaults for use on initial usage.
It prevents us from shooting ourselves in the foot by preventing us from accidentally clobbering standard macros or primitives defined by either TeX or LaTeX.
It fulfils the question's desideratum of a system in which the total and subtotals are typeset before the values are specified.

The code defines three commands for use in the document:

\total simply prints the total (defaults to 0)
\subtotal{<label>} prints the subtotal and sets the label for subsequent values (defaults to o) i.e. all values after this increment this subtotal
\nextvalue{<integer>} prints the integer and adds it to both the overall total and the current subtotal.

The upshot of this is that you can say something like
Total: \total

Subtotal: \subtotal{first}
\nextvalue{1} \nextvalue{2} \nextvalue{3} % contribute to the first subtotal

Subtotal: \subtotal{second}
\nextvalue{4} \nextvalue{5} \nextvalue{6} % contribute to the second subtotal

A slightly modified version would tweak \nextvalue to take an optional argument specifying the subtotal to add the value to. Happy to implement this if required, but, if not, we may as well go with the simpler setup.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733187/
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_cupora_total_int
\int_new:N \g_cupora_subtotal_int
\tl_new:N \g_cupora_subtotal_tl
\property_new:nnnn { cupora / total } { now } { 0 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_cupora_total_int } }
\property_new:nnnn { cupora / subtotal } { now } { 0 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_cupora_subtotal_int }}
\cs_new:Npn \cupora_total:
{
  \property_ref:nnn { final } { cupora / total } { 0 }
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument } { cupora }
{
  \property_record:ee { \g_cupora_subtotal_tl } { cupora / subtotal }
  \property_record:nn { final } { cupora / total }
}
\cs_new:Npn \cupora_subtotal:n #1
{
  \int_compare:nNnT { \g_cupora_subtotal_int } > { 0 }
  {
    \property_record:ee { \g_cupora_subtotal_tl } { cupora / subtotal }
    \int_gzero:N \g_cupora_subtotal_int
  }
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_cupora_subtotal_tl { #1 }
  \property_ref:nnn { #1 } { cupora / subtotal } { 0 }
}
\cs_new:Npn \cupora_value:n #1
{
  \int_gadd:Nn \g_cupora_subtotal_int {#1}
  \int_gadd:Nn \g_cupora_total_int {#1}
  #1
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \nextvalue \cupora_value:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \subtotal \cupora_subtotal:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \total \cupora_total:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
  Total     & \total \\
  Subtotal  & \subtotal{labelone} \\
  Values    & \nextvalue{1} \\
            & \nextvalue{1} \\
  Subtotal  & \subtotal{labeltwo} \\
  Values    & \nextvalue{2} \\
            & \nextvalue{2} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



Two anwsers in one minimal working example (mwe):


% Save it as "mwe.Rnw" (for R - Rstudio) 
% or "mwe.Rtex" ( for Overleaf) 
% or "mwe.tex" but without the R section 
% to test only the second part with a latex engine.
 
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabto}\NumTabs{5}
\begin{document}

\section*{With R \& knitr}

<<echo=F>>=
a=33
b=95  
c=73
d=46 
@
\begin{tabular}{lr}\toprule
Total:            & \Sexpr{sum(c(a,b,c,d))}\\\midrule
\quad Subtotal 1: & \Sexpr{a+b}\\
\qquad Value 1:   & \Sexpr{a}\\
\qquad Value 2:   & \Sexpr{b}\\\addlinespace
\quad Subtotal 2: & \Sexpr{c+d}\\
\qquad Value 1:   & \Sexpr{c}\\
\qquad Value 2:   & \Sexpr{d}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\newpage

\section*{Without R}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lr}}\toprule
@ Total: &  b2+b5 \\\midrule
@ \quad Subtotal 1: & b3+b4  \\
@ \qquad Value 1: &  21 \\
@ \qquad Value 2: &  56 \\\addlinespace
@ \quad Subtotal 2: & b6+b7  \\
@ \qquad Value 1: & 34  \\
@ \qquad Value 2: &  66 \\\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}


I think, your approach is not right. A calculation should look like shown below.
\TeX
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \newcount\ca
    \newcount\cb
    \newcount\cv
    \newcount\ctemp
    \newcount\csum
    \def\caddition#1#2{\ca=#1  \cb=#2 \ifnum\ca<10\ \else\fi \the\ca\ + \ifnum\cb<10\ \else\fi \the\cb\ = \advance\cv by \ca \advance\cv by \cb \hfill\the\cv \advance\ctemp by \cv \cv=0}
\def\csubtraction#1#2{\ca=#1  \cb=#2 \ifnum\ca<10 \ \else\fi\the\ca\ \ - \ifnum\cb<10 \ \else\fi \the\cb \ = \advance\cv by \ca \advance\cv by - \cb \hfill\the\cv \advance\ctemp by \cv\cv=0}
\hbox{
\vbox{\hsize=3cm
\caddition{1}{1}
    
\csubtraction{1}{1}
 
\caddition{1}{1}
 \vskip0.5\baselineskip
 \hrule
 \vskip0.5\baselineskip
 \hfill  Total = \the\ctemp
 }}
 \bye

